# Sharing through google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am Ashwin. I have a scenario on Google App Scripts. " Whenever a user clicks on the 'Create' button in Google Drive, that particular file should automatically be shared with a particular email address". Can anyone help me out in this?

Answer (score 0):

While this is possible with Google Script, an easier option would be that you create a separate folder in your Google Drive and share it with an email address. Now any file that you create inside that folder will automatically be available to that address.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion on using a folder is good. Else with script you cant hook into drives create button. But you can have a script on that user on a time trigger constantly searching for files created/modified since last time you checked and if the user is owner, share it with the other email. Even better share it with a google group so later is easier to modify the shared-to user on a single spot.